# Como coloco un boton que borre variables dentro de otro boton

Tags: javascript, botón

Hola necesito hacer una web simple que pida numeros y con botones haga operaciones basicas y debe tener un boton para borrar la informacion y hacerlo todo de nuevo el problema que tengo es que a la hora de abrir un boton de operacion no puedo retroceder ni abrir otro. Lo intente arreglar con una funcion dentro de otra pero asi ya no funciona.

Esa web solo crea las operaciones mas no puedo borrar la informacion

```js
var total
num1= Number(prompt("Escriba un numero"));
num2= Number(prompt("Escriba otro numero"));
function Sumita(){
total= num1 + num2;
var m = document.createElement("v");
var p = document.write("", total);
m.appendChild(p);
document.body.appendChild(m);
}
function Res(){
total= num1 - num2;
var m = document.createElement("v");
var p = document.write("", total);
m.appendChild(p);
document.body.appendChild(m);
}
function Divi(){
total= num1 / num2;
var m = document.createElement("v");
var p = document.write("", total);
m.appendChild(p);
document.body.appendChild(m);
}
function Multi(){
total= num1 * num2;
var m = document.createElement("v");
var p = document.write("", total);
m.appendChild(p);
document.body.appendChild(m);
}
```

```html
<h1>Escoje</h1>
<button onclick="Sumita()">Suma</button>
<button onclick="Res()">Resta</button>
<button onclick="Divi()">Division</button>
<button onclick="Multi()">Multiplicacion</button>
```

Comment: esto se da porque tienes un `document.write()`   lo que haces es remplazar el contenido de todo el doom... te recomiendo leer esto https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás no sea lo que te esten pidiendo, pues quizás tengas que usar funciones específicas para hacerlo que yo no uso en esta solución, pero yo lo haria de este modo:

```js
var num1 = Number(prompt("Escriba un número"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("Escriba otro número"));

function operacion(tipo) {
  let total = ''
  let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado')
  switch (tipo) {
    case 'sumita':
      total = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case 'res':
      total = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case 'divi':
      total = num1 / num2;
      break;
    case 'multi':
      total = num1 * num2;
      break;
  }
  resultado.innerHTML = total
}
```

```html
<h1>Escoje</h1>
<button onclick="operacion('sumita')">Suma</button>
<button onclick="operacion('res')">Resta</button>
<button onclick="operacion('divi')">Division</button>
<button onclick="operacion('multi')">Multiplicacion</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Si debes usar funciones determinadas especifícalo en la pregunta. Sino esta respuesta te podria valer supongo.

### Explicación de los cambios

- En lugar de usar 4 funciones, lo hemos pasado todo a una sola, que va a soportar todas las operaciones:

```javascript
function operacion(tipo) {
```

- Para ello, tambien hemos cambiado el HTML, pasando a estar de este modo para cada tipo de operación, llamando siempre a la misma función, pero cambiando su parámetro de tipo:

```html
<button onclick="operacion('sumita')">Suma</button>
<button onclick="operacion('res')">Resta</button>
<button onclick="operacion('divi')">Division</button>
<button onclick="operacion('multi')">Multiplicacion</button>
```

- Además, se ha agregado un nuevo elemento, en este caso un `<div>`, que nos hará de contenedor de las respuestas a las acciones de los botones, y así evitamos el uso de `document.write` y de `document.createElement("v");` (que tampoco tenia muy claro que tipo de elemento es **v** ni si realmente existe).  A este elemento lo vamos a tener que asignar después a una variable en javascript, por lo tanto mejor le ponemos un **id=** que lo identifique inequívocamente:

```
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

- Después, dentro de la función, lo que hacemos es inicializar la variable **total** con un valor vacio (una cadena o string vacio):

```
let total = ''
```

- Para después asignar el elemento anterior, el `<div>` con **id="resultado"**, a una variable que tambien vamos a denominar **resultado**:

```
let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado')
```

- Lo que viene a continuación es una declaración [switch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) que nos va a evaluar su parámetro entre sus distintos casos (case) y si alguno coincide entrará en el para ejecutar las instrucciones que solo a el le corresponden:

```
switch (tipo) {
    case 'sumita':
      total = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case 'res':
      total = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case 'divi':
      total = num1 / num2;
      break;
    case 'multi':
      total = num1 * num2;
      break;
  }
```

Como veis, su parámetro **tipo** contempla todos los casos que usamos en los botones, y en cada uno de ellos realiza la operación pertinente, y una vez la tiene asignada a la variable **total** ya podemos continuar gracias al **break** que impide que siga procesando más casos, pues ya hemos encontrado el que queríamos.

- Por último, una vez procesado el **switch**, ya tan solo nos queda poner ese **total** en el div, lo cual hacemos con la propiedad [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) sobre el elemento, que venia representado por la variable **resultado** que hemos definido al principio de la función. Esta propiedad, escrita de esta forma, mediante una igualdad, siempre va a sobreescribir lo que hayamos puesto antes dentro de ese elemento.

```
resultado.innerHTML = total
```

Comment: Si me sirve muchas gracias en serio

Comment: Pues entonces ahora la documentaré un poco, para que tengas un poco de contexto explicativo de los cambios.  Si esta respuesta ya te parece la buena deberias aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y tambien se beneficie de ello. Pulsa en [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y entender el porque es importante hacerlo. Tambien te recomiendo hacer el [ask] para que aprendas el funcionamiento de este sitio y así colabores en su buen funcionamiento, gracias.  Si aparecen nuevas y mejores respuestas después, puedes cambiar tu aceptación.

Comment: @EduardoOscal Pues ya está, he ampliado la explicación. Si recargas la página la verás (en caso de que no la veas)

Comment: Claro muchas gracias ya la coloco como aceptada

Comment: Ui, antes te pase mal el enlace... no queria mandarte a [ask] sino a [tour], que se hace en dos minutos y aprendes a groso modo el funcionamiento de este sitio, perdona (y ademas te dan una medalla al llegar al final!)

Comment: Okey ya lo leo.